# C# return keyword appears to not be working or am I loosing my mind AND tips on tree view traversing

Tags: c#, recursion, return

where I have the return statement it should exit the function however when debugging it reaches the return statement and then goes out to the last curly brackets of this function and then literally  jumps to the else statement of the if statement and then will recurse this function again however will throw an exception since the listview1.selecteditems[0].tag is null! :-S

Am I doing something wrong, loosing my mind or both?
(please ignore the functioncount variable, just there temporarily)

EDIT: One person said the return statement is behaving exactly as it should because it ends only the current invocation of the function and not any other subsequent functions.  I agree with what hes saying but my problem is I've only called this function once.  The fact that once it returns it immediately jumps to the else statement which seems to me like its bypassing the entire function?  I'm not too sure...

```
    int functionCount = 0;
    private void openTreeViewNodeBasedOnListViewItem(string treeViewNodeToOpen,TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(functionCount);
        functionCount++;
        //if (treeViewNodeToOpen.Contains(@"\"))
        //{
        //    treeViewNodeToOpen = treeViewNodeToOpen.Substring(treeViewNodeToOpen.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
        //    string[] fullNodePath = treeViewNodeToOpen.Split('\\');
        //}
        //Console.WriteLine("index {0}",listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);
        string listViewItemAddress = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString();
        string treeViewItemAddress = "";

        listViewItemAddress = listViewItemAddress.Substring(listViewItemAddress.IndexOf('\\'));
        listViewItemAddress = @"Y:\" + listViewItemAddress;
        //Console.WriteLine("List view address {0}",listViewItemAddress);

        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            treeViewItemAddress = node.FullPath.ToString();
            if (node.Text == treeViewNodeToOpen && treeViewItemAddress == listViewItemAddress)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Tree view address {0}",node.FullPath.ToString());
                functionCount = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("list view {0} match found, navigating to tree node : {1}", listViewItemAddress, node.FullPath);
                treeView1_NodeMouseClickACTION(node);
                return; //when you return here it should exit the function however when debugging it goes out to the last curly brackets of this function and then jumps to the else statement of THIS if statement and then will recurse this function again however will throw an exception since the listview1.selecteditems[0].tag is null! :-S
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("tree view node {1} does not match the node were looking for {0}", listViewItemAddress, node.FullPath);
                openTreeViewNodeBasedOnListViewItem(treeViewNodeToOpen, node.Nodes);
            }
        }

    } //after successfully finding a match and running the return statement, the debugger takes me here and then literally jumps to the else statement and I'm not quite sure why.
```

Comment: Can you tell us how and when this event is or can be raised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working exactly as it should.  `return` ends the *current invocation of the function*, and not every single invocation of the function on the call stack.  There is no keyword that would do that.

As for your specific solution, it can be re-designed to separate out some of the different tasks you're trying to accomplish, rather than doing them all in a single method, which is a part of what's giving you troubles.

One thing that you're doing is traversing a tree to get all of the nodes within it.  First write a method that does *that*, without doing anything else.  Here is one implementation of a tree traversal:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(T item, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(item);
    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;
        foreach (var child in childSelector(next))
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```

We can then invoke it like so, to get a flat sequence of all of the nodes in the tree:

```
Traverse(root, node => node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>())
```

Then we can find the first item in that sequence that has the text that we're looking for, and do something with that node:

```
TreeNode root = GetRootNode();
var result = Traverse(root, node => node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>())
    .First(node => node.Text == "some text");
DoSomethingWithNode(result);
```

Comment: Right, but I've only invoked it once...  There are only two places this function is called and they're events raised by two separate actions; or am I not understanding something?

Comment: @Ryan Other functions may only call this once, but it calls itself.  When the inner call hits a `return` it goes up to the previous invocation of this method, which is after all the method that called the current invocation.  It doesn't keep going up and up until hit hits a method with a different name.  It goes up exactly one level.

Comment: Ok, I think I follow.  Is there something I can do to make sure it quits the previous invocation once it finds a match?  Not sure I'm even asking that correctly...

Comment: @Ryan Generally speaking, no.  Specific to certain situations sure.  Generally I'd say you want a more significant re-design of your method.  Currently you're sticking too many entirely separate mechanisms into one place, and that's what's causing you problems.

Comment: Thanks a TON.  That's more help then I needed but it is greatly appreciated!  This really helped not only my application but my programming knowledge as well!  Love it when that happens.  (Not the most advanced programmer if that wasn't already obvious)

Comment: @Ryan This is a really handy method that I use frequently when dealing with treeviews, when doing all sorts of things.  This is why it's helpful to separate out the concepts.  You can write `Traverse` *once*, and then just re-use it over and over, without needing to essentially write tree traversal from scratch every time you want to search for a node and then do something with it.